# Comparing data between reporting periods MS Access

Tags: sql, ms-access, expression, ms-access-2010

I have a big table that contains records for each reporting period in my project.
The period is indentified by an integer 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7.

Each period contains about 7000 rows of tasks each identified a unique ID. These tasks all have a percent complete column which is an integer.

I want to add a comparison column.
so it would look up the unique id in the previous period then return the difference in percent complete.

eg
for
Period: 8 Item Unique ID: 42w3wer324wer32 Percent complete: 50

it would find:
Period: 7 Item Unique ID: 42w3wer324wer32 Percent complete: 40

the fill in the field with: 10.

If it could not find the Item Unique ID in the previous period then it would default to 0.

thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I understand your description, you could pull the data for period 8 like this:

```
SELECT item_id, pct_complete
FROM YourTable
WHERE rpt_period = 8;
```

And the previous period would be the same query except substituting 7 as the period.

So take the period 8 query and left join it to a subquery for period 7.

```
SELECT
    y.item_id,
    (y.pct_complete - Nz(sub.pct_complete, 0)) AS change_in_pct_complete
FROM YourTable AS y
LEFT JOIN
    (
        SELECT item_id, pct_complete
        FROM YourTable
        WHERE rpt_period = 7
    ) AS sub
ON y.item_id = sub.item_id
WHERE rpt_period = 8;
```

That `Nz()` expression will substitute 0 for Null when no period 7 match exists for a period 8 `item_id`.

If you need a query which will not be running from within an Access session, the `Nz()` function will not be available.  In that case, you can use an `IIf()` expression ... it's not as concise, but it will get the job done.

```
IIf(sub.pct_complete Is Null, 0, sub.pct_complete)
```

Comment: Thanks. is there someway to extend this so that it looks at the value of the rpt_period for a particular row item rather than explicitly stating rpt_period = 8 ?

Comment: You could use a parameter for the more recent period, and parameter -1 for the previous period.  Does that sound like what you had in mind?

Comment: yup then would I use some sort of loop to run through and change the value of the parameter?

Comment: I ended up adding an extra column that is equal to rpt_period - 1. This then lets me run it against the whole existing database as a batch.